# jQuery fade in / fade out dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie to jQuery ... having a few problems getting code to work as I want.

I've looked through similar question on this forum but can't get any suggested solutions to work.

I've set up a horizontal dropdown menu. It works fine when a top-level link is hovered over (sub-menus animate as expected) BUT I can't get the sub-menus to fade out when the mouse leaves the link.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's my code, so far (HTML and jQuery, I won't show CSS because there's a truckload of it but it's all pretty standard):

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-container">
    <nav id="menu-wrap">    
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Categories</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">CSS</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Item 11</a></li>

                                <li><a href="">Item 12</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 13</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 14</a></li>
                            </ul>               
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Graphic design</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Item 21</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 22</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 23</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 24</a></li>
                            </ul>               
                        </li>
              </ul>
           </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#menu>li').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').css({'opacity':0,'margin-    top':20}).show().animate({'margin-top':1,'opacity':1},300);
},function(){
 $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut("slow");

.});
```

---

Thanks to all those guys who responded with suggested answers. I've checked them all out and all work fine.

However, the problem still exists and I thinks it has to do with my CSS. In the CSS the nested  tags (within dropdown menu) have display property set to none:

```
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

What's happening (I think) is that when mouse is moved away from menu, the CSS kicks in, overides the jQuery, and the nested  tags are immediately reset to display:none. The fadeOut("slow") function doesn't get a chance to happen.

```
$('#menu>li').hover(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').css({'opacity':0,'margin-        top':20}).show().animate({'margin-top':1,'opacity':1},300);
   },function(){
   $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut("slow");

 });
```

Can anyone show me how to have the sub-menus set to invisible on page load, but also respond fully to jQuery when a user hovers over menu so that the sub-menus animate in and also fade out??

Comment: your jquery has syntax error. Remove `.` from last line

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu >li').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').css({'opacity':0,'margin-    top':20}).show().animate({'margin-top':1,'opacity':1},300);
},function(){
 $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut("slow");

});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/S93Ng/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works fine but I've since discovered the problem that's causing the code to work incorrectly. I'll post the question again in this light.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="nav-container">
    <nav id="menu-wrap">    
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Categories</a>
                    <ul id="submenu">
                        <li >
                            <a href="">CSS</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Item 11</a></li>

                                <li><a href="">Item 12</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 13</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 14</a></li>
                            </ul>               
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Graphic design</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Item 21</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 22</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 23</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 24</a></li>
                            </ul>               
                        </li>
              </ul>
           </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<script>            
$('#menu>li').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').css({'opacity':0,'margin-    top':20}).show().animate({'margin-top':1,'opacity':1},300);
},function(){
 $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut("slow");

});
$('#submenu>li').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').css({'opacity':0,'margin-    top':20}).show().animate({'margin-top':1,'opacity':1},300);
},function(){
 $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut("slow");

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works fine but I've since discovered the problem that's causing the code to work incorrectly. I'll post the question again in this light.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
$("a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$(this).parent().children(":not(a)").slideToggle();
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3RtD/9/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works fine but I've since discovered the problem that's causing the code to work incorrectly. I'll post the question again in this light.